# UItableview - Set cell to "loading" if empty remove header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a uitableview that loads some data from the web using hpple. I have set the cells originally to "loading..." with this method

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if ([mealInfo isEqualToString:@"Lunch"] || [mealInfo isEqualToString:@"Dinner"]  || [mealInfo isEqualToString:@"Latenight"]) {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            if (_deli == nil || _deli.count == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return _deli.count;
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if (_entrees == nil || _entrees.count == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return _entrees.count;
            }
            break;
     }
}
```

And this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (_deli == nil) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading...";
        }
        else if (_deli.count > 0) {
            Items *thisDeli = [_deli objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = thisDeli.title;
        }
        else
            cell.textLabel.text = @"No Data Available";

    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        if (_entrees == nil) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading...";
        }
        else if (_entrees.count > 0) {
            Items *thisEntree = [_entrees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = thisEntree.title;

        }
        else
            cell.textLabel.text = @"No Data Available";
    }
}
```

Instead of setting it to no data available if there is no data for that section, I want to set the header of that section to 0.

I have tried using this

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

//NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]);

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"No Data Available"]) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 30.0f;
}

}
```

But it hasn't worked?

This is how I load that data

```
-(void)getEntrees:(NSData*)entreeData {

TFHpple *Parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:entreeData];

// 3
NSString *XpathQueryString = self.entreeString;
NSArray *Nodes = [Parser searchWithXPathQuery:XpathQueryString];

// 4
NSMutableArray *newNodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (TFHppleElement *element in Nodes) {
    // 5
    Items *item = [[Items alloc] init];
    [newNodes addObject:item];

    // 6
    item.title = [[element firstChild] content];
    item.title = [[[element firstChild] content]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

    // 7
    item.url = [element objectForKey:@"href"];
}

// 8
_entrees = newNodes;
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it copy and paste

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    if (_deli == nil) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading...";
    }
    else if (_deli.count > 0) {
        Items *thisDeli = [_deli objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = thisDeli.title;
    }
    else
        cell.textLabel.text = @"No Data Available";

}
else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    if (_entrees == nil) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading...";
    }
    else if (_entrees.count > 0) {
        Items *thisEntree = [_entrees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = thisEntree.title;

    }
    else
        cell.textLabel.text = @"No Data Available";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may have copied your code in incorrectly?  But if not, 1) you need to dequeue a cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Move these lines to the start of that method:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

2) In `heightForHeaderInSection` you are testing the cell label text but using a cell you have freshly dequeued - this will be unconfigured, so will not have the text your looking for.  But you shouldn't use the cell label text to determine the header height.  Use the same logic as you use in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  So in `heightForHeaderInSection`, use:

```
if (section == 1) {
    if (_entrees != nil && _entrees.count == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 30.0f;
    }
}
```

and amend `numberOfRowsInSection` to return 0 if _entrees.count is 0, as follows:

```
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        if (_deli == nil || _deli.count == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return _deli.count;
        }
        break;

    case 1:
        if (_entrees == nil /* don't need this --> || _entrees.count == 0*/) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return _entrees.count;
        }
        break;
 }
```

Comment: I had that cell in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, i just copied wrong. And okay that works but what if I have multiple section that are blank

Comment: Can you expand on your comment?  Can't just use `switch (section) ...` in place of the `if (section == 1) ...` statement, and test each case accordingly?

Comment: okay but now the "No data available" cell us just put into the section before it

Comment: Isn't that what you are trying to achieve?  Can you explain further what you want to happen?

Comment: So the header for that section is now gone but the cell that used to be in that old section that says no data available cell is in the next section, I also want that cell gone. Does that make sense?

Comment: Amend the logic in `numbersOfRowsInSection` so that (for section 1) it returns 0 if _entrees.count is 0 (it currently returns 1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62205/discussion-between-dave-needleman-and-pbasdf).